# Freeform Next - Submit rendering

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I need to edit the HTML for the submit buttons when using Freeform Next so I can add a next/prev arrow. I've added my custom formatting template, but when I try changing the submit code only, it shows only one button even when there is a previous button.

I've tried the following, but not sure how to get the previous button to show as well, when I display the field types in the loop, it shows only one submit type when both the next/prev are there. Does anybody have anymore info about how the submit field is rendered or how I can edit both buttons?

```
{if field:type == 'submit'}
    <button type="submit" class="btn">{field:label} <svg width="16" height="16"><use xlink:href="#sprite-rightArrow"></use></svg></button>
{if:else}
    {field:render
        class="freeform-input"
        label_class="freeform-label{if field:required} freeform-required{/if}{if field:input_only} freeform-input-only-label{/if}"
        error_class="freeform-errors"
        instructions_class="freeform-instructions"
    }
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using with a multi-page form and the Submit button handling is a bit complex when displaying both buttons together, there may not exactly be a way to handle this within the template.

However, it'll look a little ugly, but you can probably place that SVG code directly into Composer for the labels of the buttons.